# RubyMotion : SecKeychainFindGenericPassword & Can't find pointer description for type '^'

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, rubymotion, macruby

I'm trying to retrieve a password from a keychain with rubyMotion, **on OS X**

I tried this :

```
#   passsword_data_pointer=Pointer.new(:object) #works but empty password
#   password_data_pointer=Pointer.new('^') #makes ruby crash and complain 'Can't find pointer description for type '^'
    password_data=NSMutableData.new #works but empty password

    password_length = Pointer.new('I')
    result=SecKeychainFindGenericPassword (
                                           nil,
                                           "some_service_string".length,
                                           "some_service_string",
                                           "some_username_string".length,
                                           "some_username_string",
                                           password_length,
                                           password_data_pointer,#or password_data.bytes
                                           nil
                                           )

#    password_string=NSMutableData.dataWithBytes(password_data.bytes, length:password_length[0])
    password_string=NSMutableData.dataWithBytes(password_data_pointer, length:password_length[0])

    p password_string
```

No matter what I do, no way to retrieve the password.

Please help ; searched for ages, the Internet is full of macruby or cocoa or c examples, but nothing for rubymotion on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with SecKeychainFindGenericPassword but I know that you need to set the proper entitlement to use the Keychain as discussed in the [RubyMotion Project Management Guide](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/project-management/#_entitlements).

So you make sure you have the following line in your Rakefile:

```
app.entitlements['keychain-access-groups'] = [
  app.seed_id + '.' + app.identifier
]
```

If you'd like a nicer interface to the Keychain, I use the [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain) cocoa wrapper which can be pulled in via Cocoapods.

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'cocoapods',        '~> 0.23.0'
gem 'motion-cocoapods', '~> 1.3.6'
```

Also in the Rakefile:

```
app.pods do
  pod 'SSKeychain', '~> 1.2.0'
end
```

Here's a simplified version of the wrapper I use for storing and retrieving sensitive data with SSKeychain:

```
class CredentialStore
  SERVICE = 'YOUR_APP_NAME'

  def set_secure_value(value, for_key: key)
    if value
      SSKeychain.setPassword(value, forService: SERVICE, account: key)
    else
      SSKeychain.deletePasswordForService(SERVICE, account: key)
    end
  end

  def secure_value_for_key(key)
    SSKeychain.passwordForService(SERVICE, account: key)
  end
end
```

Let me know if you have any further questions. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for shiming in. Should have made it more clear I'm targetting OS X !

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. Still, you might want to give SSKeychain a shot. It is compatible with either Mac OSX or iOS.